# Separating edges starting from same node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have following code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc,shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.0cm,thick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black,minimum size=45pt]

  \node[state]         (A) {$A$};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A] {$B$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=B] {$C$};


  \path (A) [loop above] edge (A);
  \path (A) edge (B) 
        (B)  edge  (C) 
        (A) edge [bend left=45] node [above, xshift=-2mm,yshift=-3.5mm,very near start] {$1$} (B)  
        (A) edge [bend left=45] (C);

 % Hard-coded the token location since i don't know about it.
 \fill[black] (0.00,1.75) circle  (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates an image like this -

[image]

However, I would like to add some text to the edges. Thus I want to have my output something like this - 
[image]

How can I achieve this in the Tikz?

Thanks !
Raj

Comment: Does setting `bend left=25` for the edge from A to B achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: oh yes ! I tried and it worked ! :) 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every tikz node has 360 anchor points using the notation `nodename.angle`, being `angle` an integer between 0 and 360. Those anchors are placed at the intersection between the node shape and a radius with the given angle. You can use those anchors to set the starting point of the arcs, and also for the labels with `$1$`.

**UPDATE**: Also, a small improvement about the dot you place "manually". It is more convenient giving the coordinates of that point in polar coordinates with respect node `A`. The point is located at 9mm at north of `A.north`, so you can specify its coordinates as `(A.north) +(90:9.1mm)`.  The `9.1mm`  part is still manually estimated, but making the coordinates relative saves you from recalculate them if you move the `A` node.

Quoting only the relevant part:

```
  \path (A) [loop above] edge (A);
  \path (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge  (C) 
        (A.20) edge [bend left=30]  (B)  
        (A.22) node[above] {$1$}
        (A.50) edge [bend left=45] (C)
        (A.52) node[above] {$1$};

  \fill[black] (A.north) +(90:9.1mm) circle  (2pt);
```

Produces:

[image: Result]

## Second update

The proper way of adding the token in the edge is to use a `markings` decoration. The syntax is a bit utgly because the decoration has to be added in a `postaction`, but using the example provided below you can easily add tokens to any edge in your graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{ % Use this style and postaction={decorate} to put a token in an edge
  put token/.style={
     decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle(2pt); }},
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.0cm,thick]
  \tikzset{
    every state/.append style={fill=white,draw=black,text=black,minimum size=45pt},
    every edge/.append style={->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt}
  }

  \node[state]   (A) {$A$};
  \node[state]   (B) [right of=A] {$B$};
  \node[state]   (C) [right of=B] {$C$};

  \path (A) edge[loop above, put token, postaction={decorate}] (A);
  \path (A) edge (B) 
        (B) edge  (C) 
        (A.20) edge [bend left=30]  (B)  
        (A.22) node[above] {$1$}
        (A.50) edge [bend left=45] (C)
        (A.52) node[above] {$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: ah this is great ! :)

Comment: even the dot improvement looks good...
I was going to put something like this - 
`node[midway,above=-7pt] {\tikz\fill circle (3pt);}` but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: @RajTendulkar I added an example of using `decorations.markings` to put the token at the correct place in a general way. It looks the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc,shapes, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.0cm,thick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,text=black,minimum size=45pt]

  \node[state]         (A) {$A$};
  \node[state]         (B) [right of=A] {$B$};
  \node[state]         (C) [right of=B] {$C$};


  \path (A) [loop above] edge (A);
  \path (A) edge (B) 
        (B)  edge  (C) 
        (A) edge [bend left=30] node [above, xshift=-1mm,yshift=-0.85mm,very near start] {$1$} (B)  
        (A) edge [bend left=50] node [above, xshift=-5mm,yshift=-3.5mm,very near start] {$1$} (C);

 % Hard-coded the token location since i don't know about it.
 \fill[black] (0.00,1.75) circle  (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```